# How to apply the `__ramfunc` instrinsic to a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, embedded, iar

I need to put all my code in ram (I'm writing the flash). I'm using IAR 7.80 and everything works fine with the `__ramfunc` intrinsic on every function but not for the C++ constructors.

For example I have the following class:

```
class Os_Timer {
  private:
    os_tmrcnt_t tmr;
  public:
    __ramfunc Os_Timer() { reset(); }
    __ramfunc void reset() { os_TimerStart( &tmr ); }
};
```

I haven't find a way to define the constructor Os_Timer in ram. The compiler complains

> expected an identifier

and

> object attribute not allowed

on the constructor line.

The IAR manual says that the `__ramfunc` has to be placed before the return value but the constructor doesn't have a return value.

I have tried without success to force the `__ramfunc` behaviour:

```
_Pragma("location=\"section  .textrw\"")
```

and

```
_Pragma("location=\"RAM_region\"")
```

Someone know how to do it?

Comment: The C++ Standard has an answer - attributes like this should be written as `[[__ramfunc]]`. But it appears that IAR does not follow the C++ standard and made up their own extension. And it's this deviation from the standard which directly causes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply `__ramfunc` to a C++ constructor you have to use `_Pragma("object_attribute=__ramfunc")` as in the example below.

```
class Os_Timer
{
private:
  os_tmrcnt_t tmr;

public:
  _Pragma("object_attribute=__ramfunc") Os_Timer() { reset(); }
  __ramfunc void reset() { os_TimerStart(&tmr); }
};
```

Note that it for this to work `os_TimerStart` should also be declared as `__ramfunc`, otherwise `os_TimerStart` will be placed in flash and may be overwritten by your flash update. To help you detect this the compiler will issue a warning if you try to call a function that is not declared as `__ramfunc` from a function that is.

Comment: Great it works! Thank you very much! The compiler warns me of functions and variables used by a ramfunc (rom access from ramfunc). Unfortunately IAR (at least the 7.80 release) doesn't issue the same warning for the constructors.